# I would like to ship a Laravel app in a Docker container, should I use Docker in Docker or docker-compose to add all services?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a Laravel app that behaves like a SaaS application. For it to work I have the following containers:

- php
- nginx
- a queue container (running laravel horizon)
- redis
- mysql
- could become more...

For development I created shares to my local codebase. Now my question is: what is the most professional way to ship such a multi-service application. I know it't not just creating a single ubuntu container running all services.

This is my current **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  store:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: redis:4.0.11-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

  database:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mysql:5.7.27
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      # So you can use a database client on your host machine
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  php:
    restart: unless-stopped
    #    image: php:7.3.10-fpm-alpine
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/dockerfiles/PHP/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
      - code-sync:/code:nocopy
      - terminal-history:/root/
      - ./docker/config/php-fpm/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/config/php-fpm/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

  queue:
    image: custom-laravel_php
    entrypoint: php artisan horizon
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
      - code-sync:/code:nocopy

  webserver:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:1.15.0-alpine
    depends_on:
      - database
      - store
      #      - certbot
      - php
    ports:
      # Exposing both http and https
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - code-sync:/code:nocopy
      - ./docker/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

volumes:
  mysql-data:
  redis-data:
  terminal-history:
  code-sync:
    external: true
```

Comment: I would add the queue into the same container as the php, unless you are expected to have a huge load. Everything else looks good, having mysql and redis on separate containers is definitely better.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to ship a Laravel app in a Docker container,

When I was working professional with Laravel I started the [Php Docker Stack](https://packagist.org/packages/exadra37-docker/php-docker-stack), a composer package to deploy Laravel with docker into production, because all the solutions on time where with focus in a development workflow, but meanwhile I moved to work in Security, and stopped it's development, but you can use it as a starting point for your professional deployment, because it separates each service into its own container.

The development stack is then extended from the production stack, not the other way around as seen in many other stacks.

> should I use Docker in Docker or docker-compose to add all services?

Docker in Docker is for docker development, and some use it in CI pipelines and even here use it with caution as per [the words of the creator](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/):

> The primary purpose of Docker-in-Docker was to help with the development of Docker itself. Many people use it to run CI (e.g. with Jenkins), which seems fine at first, but they run into many “interesting” problems that can be avoided by bind-mounting the Docker socket into your Jenkins container instead.

### Professional Deployment

> Now my question is: what is the most professional way to ship such a multi-service application.

It really depends on the technical level of your client user base, but you can start with docker compose, and then upgrade to Docker Swarm or Even Kubernetes.

Try to provide all images from an upstream private registry, instead of building them locally, as you do in some of them.

### Security

#### Database ports

```
    ports:
      # So you can use a database client on your host machine
      - 3306:3306
```

This `3306:3306` equivalent to `0.0.0.0:3306:3306`, thus if you want the database to be available only in localhost you should do instead `127.0.0.1:3306:3306`, but if your database only needs to be available to the other containers in the stack then you can remove the ports altogether, and instead you can call the database from your code by using the docker compose service name, that in your case is `database`.

#### Database Password

```
environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

A better way to provide secrets is to set them in the `.env` file at the root of your project, and then use variables in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD? Missing password for mysql root user.}
```

Or just replace `environment:` on your `docker-compose.yml` with the `.env` file in the root of your project:

```
env_file:
    - ./.env
```